# Trying to figure out how to add this javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

So i want to make a list of these orders and implement a search function to it but i cant even figure the basics like now it just spams undefined on the html even though the "orderid" is a object on the json file. this is really hard to figure out and when i ask people, people give too straight forward messages to me that i cant figure it im not asking you guys to code for me but to point to right direction would helpful

```js
const orderlist = document.getElementById('orderlist');
let orderid = [0];

const loadorders = async() => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch('https://www.cc.puv.fi/~asa/cgi-bin/fetchOrders.py');
    orderid = await res.json();
    displayorderid(orderid);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    console.log(res);
  }
};
const displayorderid = (orderid) => {
  const htmlString = orderid
    .map((order) => {
      return `
        <li class="orderid">
        <h2>${order.value}</h2>
        </li>
        `;
    })
    .join('');
  orderlist.innerHTML = htmlString;
};
loadorders();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  background-color: rgb(59, 59, 243);
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  color: azure margin-bottom:30px;
}

.container {
  padding: 35px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  text-align: center center;
}

#customerslist {
  padding-inline-start: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 15;
}

.Customer {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: ;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>tilaukset</h1>
  <div id="search">
    <input type="text" name="Hakupalkki" id="Hakupalkki" placeholder="Hae tilausta" />
  </div>
  <ul id="orderlist"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I turned your code into a snippet - note that this is the preferred way to present code as it allows you and others to test it right here in the question. The issue is there is no `value` property in the objects you are looping through. Examine the object by putting a `console.log(order)` in your `map` function.

Comment: What do you want to show exactly?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/05au1Qf.png I have displayed the `orderid`s @Jesse

Comment: `<h2>${orderid.orderid}</h2>`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working snippet. As mentioned by Kinglish (in the comments), the issue is there is no value property in the objects you are looping through it should say `customerid` instead.

```js
const orderlist = document.getElementById('orderlist');
let orderid = [0];

const loadorders = async() => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch('https://www.cc.puv.fi/~asa/cgi-bin/fetchOrders.py');
    orderid = await res.json();
    displayorderid(orderid);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    console.log(res);
  }
};
const displayorderid = (orderObject) => {
  const htmlString = orderObject
.map((orderObject) => {
  return `
    <li class="orderid">
    <h2>${orderObject.customerid}</h2>
    </li>
    `; //<------- the customerid property exists
})
.join('');
  orderlist.innerHTML = htmlString;
};
loadorders();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  background-color: rgb(59, 59, 243);
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  color: azure margin-bottom:30px;
}

.container {
  padding: 35px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  text-align: center center;
}

#customerslist {
  padding-inline-start: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 15;
}

.Customer {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: ;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>tilaukset</h1>
  <div id="search">
    <input type="text" name="Hakupalkki" id="Hakupalkki" placeholder="Hae tilausta" />
  </div>
  <ul id="orderlist"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Also note that Lissy93 renamed the parameter `orderid` to `orderObject`, which is more understandable. Even better would be to somehow mediate that the object in fact is an array, e.g. by naming it `orderObjects` (notice the <i>s</i>) or just `orders`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no value property of each object in the array. Try this for example:

```
const orderlist = document.getElementById('orderlist');
let orderid = [0];

const displayorderid = (orderid) => {
  const htmlString = orderid
    .map((orderid) => {
      return `
        <li class="orderid">
        <h2>${orderid.customerid}</h2>
        </li>
        `; //<------- the customerid property exists
    })
    .join('');
  orderlist.innerHTML = htmlString;
};

const loadorders = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(
      'https://www.cc.puv.fi/~asa/cgi-bin/fetchOrders.py'
    );
    orderid = await res.json();
    console.log(orderid) //<------- use this to view the each object`s properties in the console
    displayorderid(orderid);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    console.log(res);
  }
};

loadorders();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It would be good to put your answer in a snippet so we can test it.

Comment: looks like someone beat me to the punch, will note this for next time